# If the room is dark, can I still move to a closet or explore?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

When I enter a room that is "dark", can I still move to a closet or continue exploring or do I need to complete a puzzle first?

Answer (score 3):

Darkness has only 2 effects per the [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5054/if-the-room-is-pitch-dark-can-i-still-move-to-a-closet-or-explore):

1. If you want to explore, it costs you an action plus a movement step
2. -2 to all attribute tests during combat